# php values and keys setting web address

Tags: php

i am trying to set the web addresses as the valves and set the keys to be short names for the sites. Not sure where im going wrong. Everytime i try and run it it keeps saying line 11 which is $http://www.yahoo.co.uk/= array( key => value,("yahoo_uk");

```
$http://www.yahoo.co.uk/= array( key => value,("yahoo_uk");

foreach ($array as $key =>$value) {
echo $value;
}




?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

wow :P There are so many syntax errors I don't even know where to begin

Here's the correct syntax

```
 $array = array('http://www.yahoo.co.uk' => 'yahoo_uk');
```

Read this chapter of the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: OP is asking for the short name to be the key (`yahoo_uk`)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you intend to do something like:

```
$urls = array();
$urls['yahoo_uk'] = "http://www.yahoo.co.uk/";
```

This initializes an array to store URLs, then creates an array member with the short name `yahoo_uk` as key, and its corresponding URL as the value.

You can then access it with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($urls as $name => $url) {
  echo "name: $name, url: $url\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you were going for

```
<?php

    $array = array('http://www.yahoo.co.uk/' => 'yahoo_uk');

    foreach ($array as $key =>$value) {
        echo $value;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set constants within your array and you're using incorrect PHP syntax. Try this instead:

```
$urls = array('yahoo_uk' => 'http://www.yahoo.co.uk/');

foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Or calling a single value like this:

```
echo $urls['yahoo_uk']; // http://www.yahoo.co.uk/
```

Also, your question is very vague and hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$yahoo = array_assoc('http://www.yahoo.co.uk/' => 'yahoo_uk');

foreach ($yahoo as $key => $value) {
echo $value;
}
?>
```